# Code first Sharing Primary Key between tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code first to try and create a database whereby I have several tables that share unique primary keys.

I have the following structure to my domain classes, and would hope that FirstClass, SecondClass, ThirdClass would all be created as tables that link to a BaseTable where the shared keys are stored. I have included the SharedClass class in this example since I also have this strutcure in my project.

```
[Table("BaseTable")]
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SharedClass : BaseClass {
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
}

[Table("FirstClass")]
public abstract class FirstClass : SharedClass {
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
}

[Table("SecondClass")]
public abstract class SecondClass : SharedClass {
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
}

[Table("ThirdClass")]
public abstract class ThirdClass : SharedClass {
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string SharePropertyOne { get; set; }
}
```

What is currently happening is that FirstClass, SecondClass and ThirdClass are all being created but with their own primary keys and no BaseTable is being created.

I am not sure if I am missing something after looking through several questions on here that are asking something similar.

Comment: Can you show the related DbSets defined in your DbContext as well as fluent configuration if any.

Comment: So I have none of the above classes as DbSets in the Context since none of them are aggregate routes and no Fluent API configs.

Answer (score 0):

The EF inheritance is not activated by default and even by applying `Table` data annotation on a base class.

It can be activated by either adding a `DbSet` to the derived `DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<BaseClass> BaseClass { get; set; }
```

which also allows you to use polymorphic queries, or with fluent configuration - the bare minimum needed is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>();
```